# How to fix iMac keyboard delay?

Tags: keyboard, macos, imac, bluetooth

I just opened my new iMac, and the bluetooth keyboard is terrible.  When I press a key, it can take up to 3 -  5 seconds to respond, and sometimes, the keyboard acts as if I've been holding the key down.

Is there any known way to fix this?  It's extremely annoying.

Note: I'm on Yosemite

Comment: 'just opened'? Brand new from the store or it was OK but now it isn't?

Comment: It's brand new from the store.  I noticed the issue immediately after beginning to use it.

Comment: Did you set up FileVault? That will slow the machine down until it's completed. Indexing could also do it - Look at Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor & see if you can see the processes mds or mdworker looking particularly busy

Comment: I didn't set up FileValue, and none of my processes are taking up over 5% CPU

Comment: How's memory pressure? [same app] If that's still well in the green, then I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Yeah memory pressure is in the green.  I'm going into the Apple store shortly to swap this out.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome - wish you luck.